# How do I simplify the adding of 24 different integers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, integer

I'm building a game for iPhone, and I want to add 24 integers together. These 24 integers contain the total number of bombs ignited in each of the 24 levels. Here is the super crummy code i'm using right now:

```
totalBombs = level1bombs + level2bombs + level3bombs + level4bombs + level5bombs + level6bombs + level7bombs + level8bombs + level9bombs + level10bombs + level11bombs + level12bombs + level13bombs + level14bombs + level15bombs + level16bombs + level17bombs + level18bombs + level19bombs + level20bombs + level21bombs + level22bombs + level23bombs + level24bombs;
```

How can I simplify this code? 
Yes, I realize this is very poor implementation. Please be gentle with your responses.

Comment: If one of the answers helps, you are supposed to click the check by it. That tells other SO users that it has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

Make an array of the LevelBombs then do a loop over the array, adding them. In general, any time you have variables with names like

varname1

varname2

varname3

It means you need an array.

Answer (score 2):

As others say, use an array, but an `NS[Mutable]Array` array is probably overkill for a collection of 24 integers - consider using a C array. E.g.

```
unsigned LevelBombs[24];
```

(assuming the number of bombs is never negative!). You can initialize a global like this using a literal:

```
unsigned LevelBombs[24] = { 27, 42, ..., 36 };
```

and you can omit the `24` if you do this - C can count. If you omit the size you get the count using:

```
unsigned count = sizeof(LevelBombs)/sizeof(unsigned);
```

Individual elements are `LevelBombs[index]` and a simple loop will give you the total.

Wrap the whole array up in a (singleton) class if you like, with appropriate methods to modify elements, get the total etc. But wrapping each element in an `NSNumber` and the whole lot in an `NSMutableArray` is probably just memory (de)allocation work you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from using an array to store your bombs.

You could initialize the array in a couple different ways depending on what works best for your. One way would be like this which sets each level to 5.

```
int numLevels = 25;

NSMutableArray *bombs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

for (int i = 0; i < numLevels; i++) {

    [bombs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
}
```

Or - if you want to initialize the array with different values for each level you would do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *bombs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], [NSNumber numberWithInt:25], [NSNumber numberWithInt:55], [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], [NSNumber numberWithInt:200], nil];
```

And so on adding a new NSNumber for each level.

Then to access say level 1 you would do this:

```
NSNumber levelNumBombs = [bombs objectAtIndex:0];
```

or level 5 like:

```
NSNumber levelNumBombs = [bombs objectAtIndex:4];
```

To change level 5 bombs to 66 you would do something like this:

```
[bombs replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:66];
```

Then, to add everything up you would do something like this:

```
 int totalBombs = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < [bombs count]; i++) {

     totalBombs += [[bombs objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
 }
```